# DKMS: Install Failed

Tags: upgrade, kernel, dkms

Every time I upgrade the system and there is an update to the kernel I see the following error in the APT logs:

```
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-55-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-55-generic
Error! Problems with depmod detected.  Automatically uninstalling this module.
DKMS: Install Failed (depmod problems).  Module rolled back to built state.
```

What causes this? What does this mean? Do I need to fix this? How do I fix this?

**Edit:**

Here's the output of `dkms status`:

```
$ dkms status
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-54-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-55-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.16.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.16.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.16.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.16.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.16.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.16.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-349, 349.16, 3.13.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-349, 349.16, 3.13.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-349, 349.16, 3.13.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-349, 349.16, 3.13.0-54-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-349, 349.16, 3.13.0-55-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-349, 349.16, 3.16.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-349, 349.16, 3.16.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-349, 349.16, 3.16.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-349, 349.16, 3.16.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-349, 349.16, 3.16.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-349, 349.16, 3.16.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-54-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-55-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.16.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.16.0-39-generic, x86_64: built
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.16.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dkms status` terminal command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you use `Ubuntu 14.04` with kernel `3.16`.

But you have still `3.13` kernel meta packages that download and install these kernels.

Some DKMS modules do not build with those kernels. To be more precise they build but do not install correctly.

I suggest removing `3.13 meta packages` by

```
 sudo apt-get remove linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

And also you can install Synaptic and remove unneeded 3.13 linux images and headers.

Comment: Thank you, I removed everything related to the kernel 3.13 and the error is gone.

Comment: How did you remove everything?

Comment: @Goddard sudo apt-get autoremove